# Función strtol de la libreria stdlib

Tags: c

Estoy estudiando por cuenta propia las distintas funciones que nos ofrecen las librerías estándar ANSI-C. Termino de quedarme atascado con la función strtol.

```
long int strol(const char *numPtr, char **finalPtr, int base);
```

La teoria por el momento encontrada dice así:

> **strtol:**               **Convierte la porción inicial de la cadena apuntada por
> numPtr a una representación de long int**.
>
> Primero descompone la cadena de entrada en tres partes: una secuencia inicial, posiblemente vacía,
> de caracteres de espacio blanco (tal como es especificado por la
> función isspace), una secuencia fuente asemejándose a un entero
> representado en alguna base   determinado por el valor de base, y una
> cadena final de uno o más caracteres irreconocidos, incluyendo el
> carácter nulo final de la cadena entrada. Entonces, intenta convertir
> la secuencia fuente a un entero, y retorna el resultado.
>
> Si el valor de base es cero, la forma esperada de la secuencia fuente es
> aquélla de una constante entera, opcionalmente    precedida por un signo
> más o menos, pero sin incluir un sufijo entero.
> Si el valor de base está entre 2 y 36, la forma esperada de la secuencia fuente es una
> secuencia de letras y dígitos representando un entero con una base
> especificado  por base, opcionalmente precedida por un signo positivo
> o negativo, pero sin incluir un sufijo entero.
>
> Las letras de a (ó A) hasta z (ó Z) son atribuidos los valores de 10 a 35; sólo letras cuyos
> valores atribuidos son menores que aquéllos de la base están permitidos. Si el valor de base es 16, los
> caracteres 0x ó 0X puedes opcionalmente preceder la secuencia     de letras y dígitos, a continuación > del signo, si éste está presente.
>
> La secuencia fuente
> está definida como la secuencia inicial más larga de la cadena de
> entrada, comenzando por el primer carácter que no es un espacio
> blanco, que es de la forma esperada. La secuencia fuente no contiene
> caracteres si la cadena de entrada está vacía o consiste completamente de espacio en blanco, o si el primer carácter que no es
> un espacio blanco es distinto a un signo o letra o dígito permitido.
>
> Si la secuencia fuente tiene la forma esperada y el valor de base
> es cero, la secuencia de caracteres comenzando por el     primer dígito
> es interpretada como una constante entera.
> Si la secuencia fuente tiene la forma esperada y el valor de  base está entre 2 y 36, es
> usada como la base para la conversión, atribuyendo a cada letra su
> valor dado tal como descrito anteriormente.
> Si la secuencia fuente
> comienza con un signo negativo, el valor resultante de la conversión
> es negativo. Un puntero a la cadena final es guardado en el objeto
> apuntado por finalPtr, con tal de que finalPtr no es  nulo.
> Si la secuencia fuente está vacía o no tiene la forma esperada, ninguna
> conversión es realizada; el valor numPtr es guardado en el objeto
> apuntado por finalPtr, con tal de que finalPtr no es nulo.
>
> A continuación, se muestra el formato usado por esta función:
> **[eb] [sn] [0] [x] [ddd]**,donde:
>
> **[eb]** Espacio Blanco opcional Cita en bloque
>
> **[sn]** Signo opcional (+ ó -)
>
> **[0]** Cero opcional (0)
>
> **[x]** 'x' ó 'X' opcional
>
> **[ddd]** Dígitos opcionales
>
> Si base es cero, los primeros caracteres de numPtr determinan la
> base:
>
> Primer carácter -----Segundo carácter ----- Cadena interpretada como...
>
> 0 ------------------------- 1 a 7 ------------------------- Octal
> 0 ------------------------- x ó X ------------------------- Hexadecimal
> 1 a 9 ---------------------(0 a 9) ------------------------ Decimal
>
> La función strtol retorna el valor convertido, si acaso existe. Si no
> se pudo realizar ninguna conversión, cero es  retornado. Si el valor
> correcto no pertenece al intervalo de valores representables, LONG_MAX
> o LONG_MIN es     retornado (según el signo del valor), y el valor de la
> macro ERANGE es guardado en errno.

Lo que no comprendo es con que objetivo es usada esta funcion.

Por ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
 char numPtr[9] = "12345678", finalPtr;
 int base;
 for( base=0; base<=20; base++ )
 printf( "Convirtiendo la cadena \"%s\" en un numero en base %d: %u\n", numPtr,base, strtol(numPtr,finalPtr, base) );
 return 0;
}
```

Este ejemplo nos da las siguientes salidas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No comprendo el porqué de las salidas de este programa.
Comprendo que strtol guarda en forma de long int una cadena y que en base 0 y 10 devuelva el valor original de la cadena.

No comprendo la definición de "en base" pues si hablamos de binario, octal, decimal, y hexadecimal... no comprendo por qué la salida en base 2 da 1 y no la cadena transformada en binario, y lo mismo con los demás números.

Bueno en realidad esta función me tiene hecho un lio.

¿Alguien podría aclararme cual es el proceso que sigue la función para sacar estos resultados? ¿O mostrarme un ejemplo más intuitivo para el buen uso de esta función?

PD
Gracias de antemano por las molestias de leer tal parrafada ^^!

El ejemplo es sacado del manual ANSI-C de http://www.conclase.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estás interpretando mal el concepto.

Dicha función convierte el número a **decimal** siempre, la base que le pasas indica en qué base está el string que le pasas como parámetro.

Si seguimos con el ejemplo que adjuntaste, entonces, debería ser así:

```
Convirtiendo la cadena "12345678" que está en base "0" a decimal:
Convirtiendo la cadena "12345678" que está en base "1" a decimal:
Convirtiendo la cadena "12345678" que está en base "2" a decimal:
Convirtiendo la cadena "12345678" que está en base "3" a decimal:
```

**Caso 0:**

Cuando la base es 0, retorna el mismo número.

**Caso 1:**

Si decimos que el número 12345678 está en base 1, es incorrecto porque todos los números son mayores o igual que 1. La función lo interpreta así. Dado que no hay nada que sumar, entonces retorna 0.

**Caso 2:**

Si decimos que el número 12345678 está en base 2, entonces los dígitos "2345678" son incorrectos, por ende sólo se toma el primer dígito, quedándonos con 1.

```
Entonces: 1(2^0) = 1
```

**Caso 3:**

Si decimos que el número 12345678 está en base 3, entonces los dígitos "345678" son incorrectos, por ende sólo se toman los dos primeros dígitos, quedándonos con 12.

```
Entonces: 1(3^1) + 2(3^0) = 5
```

**Caso 4:**

Si decimos que el número 12345678 está en base 4, entonces los dígitos "45678" son incorrectos, por ende sólo se toman los tres primeros dígitos, quedándonos con 123.

```
Entonces: 1(4^2) + 2(4^1) + 3(4^0) = 27
```

---

Entonces, **strtol** te permite transformar un numero de un string usando el [teorema fundamental de la numeración](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_numeraci%C3%B3n#:%7E:text=Teorema%20fundamental%20de%20la%20numeraci%C3%B3n,-Este%20teorema%20establece&text=El%20valor%20total%20del%20n%C3%BAmero,que%20ocupa%20en%20el%20n%C3%BAmero) para devolvernos el valor según la base en decimal.

Por ejemplo:

Transformar y guardar un string con valor **binario** en decimal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  char numPtr[10] = "00000101", finalPtr;
  long Maux;
  
  Maux = strtol(numPtr, finalPtr, 2);
  printf("convertintendo la cadena %s en un numero decimal en base 2: %u",numPtr2, Maux);
  return 0;
}  // la salida sera 5
```

Transformar y guardar un string con valor **hexadecimal** en decimal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
 char numPtr[10] = "1B6CD", finalPtr;
 long Maux;

 Maux = strtol(numPtr, finalPtr, 16);
 printf("convertintendo la cadena %s en un numero decimal en base 16: %u",numPtr2, Maux);
 return 0;
} // la salida sera 112333
```

Comment: Entonces en caso 5: 1(5^3) + 2(5^2) + 3(5^1) + 4(5^0) = 125 + 50 +15 + 4 = 194!!! 
:O!!! GRACIAS!!!! Aun no comprendo lo que estoy haciendo, pero creo que lo estoy entendiendo.
¿Las operaciones que hace por número serian raíces?
Y esta propiedad en base otros números que no sean 0 o 10 en que pueden ser útiles?

Comment: Las operaciones son debido al Teorema Fundamental de numeración: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_numeraci%C3%B3n#:~:text=Teorema%20fundamental%20de%20la%20numeraci%C3%B3n,-Este%20teorema%20establece&text=El%20valor%20total%20del%20n%C3%BAmero,que%20ocupa%20en%20el%20n%C3%BAmero.

Comment: Fantastico!! :D Muchas gracias por la colaboracion, lo he comprendido!

Esta funcion te permite copiar una cadena i segun la base en la que operes te dara el valor en decimal!

por ejemplo: 101 en base 2 nos dara 5 que es el valor en decimal del numero binario 101. Tambien puede ser una  cadena en hexadecimal como el numero '1B6CD' que en base 16 nos dara 112333 que es el balor en el sistema decimal!!

De verdad muchas gracias por la ayuda!!